# Associate stackapps account with careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, stackapps

Now that [stackapps](http://stackapps.com) is up and running, it would be good if accounts on it could be associated with a careers profile the same way they already can for the SOFU sites. As stackapps is very specific to the development of applications, it seems like it would be very appropriate for a potential employer to be able to see a user's posts on stackapps.

Comment: For the uninitiated *(i.e. me, among others)* - what is stackapps? And where can I look at it?

Comment: @dboardman: added a link to the site.

Comment: I guess the beta sign ups are by invite only? I guess I need to catch up with stuff on stackexchange.

Comment: @dboar what? no, it's a public beta, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/

Comment: @Jeff, well I wasn't sure because when I tried to get a key, I got a message that the system couldn't log in and retrieve my OpenID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done, you should be able to associate your stackapps account with careers now.

Comment: Whoops, it even went *automagically* on first login with my OpenID.

Comment: I see the option to associate my acccount with StackApps, but my StackApps flair doesn't appear on my CV after I click the button. What gives?