# Include Markdown post bodies in the data dump

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, data-dump

I want to get the Stack Overflow data dump in Markdown format, for testing [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp) on real content.

Could this please be added to the data dump?

The dump body of this post: [StackApps Flair on Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51181/stackapps-flair-on-careers) is:

```
<p>I'm trying to get my <strong>StackApps flair to display on my Careers CV</strong>.</p>

<p>The <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/associate-stackapps-account-with-careers/">Meta question "Associate StackApps account with Careers"</a> is marked as <code>status-completed</code> and I do see the association button on Careers, but after I click it, nothing happens! </p>

<p>Is this the right procedure to get my StackApps flair to appear, or am I forgetting/missing something?</p>
```

But the Markdown content if the same text will be:

```
I'm trying to get my **StackApps flair to display on my Careers CV**.

The [Meta question "Associate StackApps account with Careers"][1] is marked as `status-completed` and I do see the association button on Careers, but after I click it, nothing happens!

Is this the right procedure to get my StackApps flair to appear, or am I forgetting/missing something?

  [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/associate-stackapps-account-with-careers/
```

Comment: personally I think only the markdown should be supplied, we can always transform it to html anyway

Comment: Related: [Include revision history in the public data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40733/include-revision-history-in-the-public-data-dump)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now get the raw markdown in the new PostHistory XML included with the latest dump. Please see [Anatomy of a Data Dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump) for a description of all the new fields.