# Does data explorer give access to the markdown version of post? (photobucket issue)

Tags: support, search, markdown, data-explorer, imgur

Photobucket has gone [bad](http://photobucket.com/p500), so I've a number of old posts across the network which have broken images as I made them prior to the imgur deal.

The internal search doesn't work - "user:me photobucket" has 0 results - so the best I've been able to do so far is a google search "site:meta.stackexchange.com adam davis photobucket" which does produce some results, but I'm not sure it catches all of them.

I want to fix them, but I don't have the time right now, and when I do have time I don't want to re-educate myself on the data explorer, so:

Is there a simple search I can perform on the data explorer, or is there a better way, to figure out which of my posts still need correction?

I recognize that due to licensing issues Stack Exchange probably can't just slurp the images over from one service to the other or automate it for us, and I suspect that it's not a big issue since it was so long ago, and people are fixing relevant posts as they run into them, so putting much effort into automating it probably isn't warranted, but a method to discover my own would be nice.

<sup><sub>yes this is a plzsndmetehcodez question, downvote accordingly...</sub></sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `url` search parameter:

> [`user:2915 url:photobucket.com`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A2915+url%3Aphotobucket.com)

That does return results for me but has the disadvantage you have to run this on each site you have an account on. Not funny if you have signed up on hundreds of them.

Better leverage SEDE with this [network wide query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/708845?accountid=2114) but prepare for timeouts if you expect a lot of results.

Comment: The majority of the sites were created after the integration with imgur, so most people will only have to search meta, stack overflow, superuser, and serverfault. Thanks for the search lead, this is much easier than parsing a DE query!

Comment: Thanks for both the simple query and the network wide query! I admit I haven't been able to wrap my head around the network wide queries on DE yet, so this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. The current version of the post, stored in `Posts.Body`, is HTML, but the `PostHistory` table contains the Markdown source in the `Text` column. It's all described in the [schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232) and it was probably introduced alongside [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51177/295232).