# StackApps Flair on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, flair, stackapps

I'm trying to get my **StackApps flair to display on my Careers CV**.

The [Meta question "Associate StackApps account with Careers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/associate-stackapps-account-with-careers/) is marked as `status-completed` and I do see the association button on Careers, but after I click it, nothing happens!

Is this the right procedure to get my StackApps flair to appear, or am I forgetting/missing something?

Comment: There were some errors being swallowed.  Try again now.

Comment: @David: it worked this time! Thanks!

Also, you should add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed!  Some recent account association changes on the Trilogy were breaking Careers account association.